# Why doesn't this piece of code output anything?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
        var per1 = { name: "john", age: 23 }; 
        var per2 = { name: "Robin", age: 10 };
        var per3 = { name: "temp", age: 15 };

        var people = new Array(3);
        people[0] = per1;
        people[1] = per2;
        people[2] = per3;

        function select()
        {
            document.write("test");
            for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++)
            {
                if (people[i].age < 20)
                    document.write(people[i].name + "<br/>");
            }

        }

    </script>

    <header id="temp">temp</header>
    <input type="button" value="touch me" onclick="select()" />

</body>
</html>
```

I'm totally new to javascript. This is the code I wrote. I couldn't find anything wrong with this piece of code. Can anyone help? Thank you. The problem is when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, you don't need to set the array boundary `new Array(3)` you can simply do `= []`

Comment: document.write("test") is working?

Comment: Please consider giving this question a better title.

Comment: no "test" doesn't show up.

Comment: @RUJordan or just var `people = [{ name: "john", age: 23 }, { name: "Robin", age: 10 }, { name: "temp", age: 15 }];`

Comment: I don't know what you want with this code, but use console.log() instead of document.write(), and press F12 on your google chrome and go to "Console".

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem is when I click the button. "test" doesn't even show up. So It didn't go to the select function.

Comment: Change select() to something else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't this piece of code output anything?

Because your function name conflicts with the `select` method of the `window` object, since global functions are thrown onto `window`. If you change your function name to something else (`foo`, for instance), it'll work in that you'll get your page replaced with the word `"test"` (at least).

[Here's a live copy](http://jsbin.com/yayoyeki/1) of your code, which doesn't work, and [here's a copy](http://jsbin.com/yayoyeki/2) with the function name changed to `foo`, which does.

This is one of the *many* reasons to avoid using globals. In this case, for instance, you could give your button an `id` (`id="theButton"`) and no `onclick`, then use this minimally-modified script:

```
(function() {
  var per1 = { name: "john", age: 23 }; 
  var per2 = { name: "Robin", age: 10 };
  var per3 = { name: "temp", age: 15 };

  var people = new Array(3);
  people[0] = per1;
  people[1] = per2;
  people[2] = per3;

  document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = select;

  function select()
  {
      document.write("test");
      for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++)
      {
          if (people[i].age < 20)
              document.write(people[i].name + "<br/>");
      }
  }
})();
```

That works because `select` is no longer global, and so no longer conflicts.

---

Just for what it's worth, [here's a version](http://jsbin.com/yayoyeki/3) that doesn't use `document.write` (best avoided), hooks up the handler with code, and uses array literal notation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="temp">temp</header>
    <input type="button" value="touch me" id="theButton" />
    <!-- Note that the script is *below* the content it uses -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    (function(){
        var people = [
            { name: "john", age: 23 },
            { name: "Robin", age: 10 },
            { name: "temp", age: 15 }
        ];

        document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = run;

        function run()
        {
            display("test");
            for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++)
            {
                if (people[i].age < 20)
                {
                    display(people[i].name);
                }
            }
        }

        function display(msg) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = String(msg);
            document.body.appendChild(p);
        }
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```